# How can I remove the sidebar from the following Bootstrap theme?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

With reference to the following page:

http://coderthemes.com/simple/light/extras-pricing.html

When I try deleting the aside tags, I get a blank placeholder where the left navigation used to be.

How can I delete the left navigation entirely so that the 'Pricing' pane stretches horizontally across the whole of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the entire HTML that has the class `sidebar-navigation` and apply `margin-left: 0px;` of the element `#page-right-content` in your CSS.

[image]

Comment: Please don't answer off topic questions. Answer well-asked questions

Not all questions can or should be answered here. Avoid trying to answer questions which...
    ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem...don't supply code on this site...
    ...solicit opinions rather than facts." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer When his link dies tomorrow or next year, this question dies with it cause no one will know what he's talking about. Your answer makes no sense without his link working, also.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that even without a working link, the question and answer makes sense to anyone has ever coded and can use a bit of common sense.

Comment: @Mary Common sense would tell you that you can't fix code without the code that needs fixing and you failed to follow Stack Overflow policy by not supplying the code on Stack Overflow as required. [mcve]